# Scrolling Behavior of Background Image on Deployed Website Is Erratic. It Is Supposed To Be Stationery, Expected Behavior On Local Build

Tags: javascript, html, css

Built a Jekyll website based on a 3-party theme (MASSIVELY).

Code of website available here: https://git.ikrypto.club/FNB_Japan/FNBJapan

When you visit the deployed website, the background image does not remain constant as expected (You can kind of see the expected behavior on the theme demo, https://iwiedenm.github.io/jekyll-theme-massively/ (Edit: This is actually a better example, https://massively.ghost.io/ ). Basically, the background image is expected to remain constant, and the foreground should scroll with the user.).

You can witness the difference in behavior if you go on our website, https://fnb-japan.info .

However, when the code is ran locally and built with

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

The background image does not move (as expected). What's happening and how can I remedy it?

Note: It appears that this problem only appears on FF Nightly, and not Chrome

Edit: This appears to be a problem with Firefox Nightly, as opposed to the website. This question is technically resolved.

Edit 2: It appears that the problem persists, and is due to a bad implementation of parallax scrolling causing parallax to flicker.

Edit 3: This problem only occurs once the window is of a certain width, and the difference isn'ta ctually between local/deployed but rather different window sizes.

Comment: The background does scroll on my Chrome too (and pretty erratically)

Comment: +AKX thank you, that is very helpful to know. It's really weird that this doesn't appear to be consistent behavior, and that I can't replicate it on local builds

Answer (score 0):

The background div (`#bg`) 
 is being transformed by 
[this code in the bundled parallax plugin](https://git.ikrypto.club/FNB_Japan/FNBJapan/src/master/jekyll/assets/js/main.js#L54-L61) (as evident from setting a "break on attribute modification" on the bg element in the Chrome inspector), which in kind seems to be activated by [this](https://git.ikrypto.club/FNB_Japan/FNBJapan/src/master/jekyll/assets/js/main.js#L132) invocation:

```
// Background.
$wrapper._parallax(0.925);
```

Removing those lines should get rid of the parallax effect too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't actually want to disable Parallax, just want it to stop flickering. Instead, I want the background image to be fixed at a specific location, and never move while the foreground scrolls.